# How to define PVC for specific path in a single node in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am running local k8s cluster and defining PV as hostPath for mysql pods.
Sharing all the configuration details below .

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

The problem I am getting is as mysql pod is running in k8s cluster ,when its deleted and recreate ,it will choose any one of the node and deployed .So mysql hostpath always mounted to specific node .Is it a good idea to fix the node for mysql or any other options are there ?please share if any idea .

Answer (score 1):

you have below choices

1. Use node selector or node affinity to ensure that pod gets scheduled on the node where the mount is created OR
2. Use local persistent volumes. it is supported on kubernetes 1.14 and above

Comment: thank you ,using node affinity can I use master node ?

Comment: yes, you can. provided the master is allowed to run work loads

Comment: nodeSelector, although is easier to implement, is not intended for these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a PVC and a PV? Actually, for hostPath, you don't even need to create the PV object. It just gets it.

You should use a StatefulSet if you want a pod that is re-created to get the storage it was using the previous one (state).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  serviceName: "mysql"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mysql-persistent-storage
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      # storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

This statefulSet fails, but it is a mysql thing. As reference, should serve.